# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen ansagen und vorhersagen?

Tags: word-choice, meaning-in-context, usage

Eine Freundin hat mir geschrieben:

> Das Eis ist **angesagt.**

Aber ist es nicht eine Wetter_vorhersage_? Warum ist das folgende nicht besser?

> Das Eis ist **vorhergesagt.**

Comment: Willkommen bei German.SE. In welchem Kontext entstand die Original-Aussage (z.B. eins, zwei Sätze vorher/Thema)? D.h., meine Rückfrage ist: wenn es nicht um Wettervorhersage geht, warum sollte es besser sein zu sagen 'vorhergesagt'?

Comment: Wenn etwas _angesagt_ ist, kann es auch gerade _in Mode_ sein, abhängig vom Kontext.

Comment: Wenn, dann vorhergesagt, nicht vorhersagt.

Comment: @userunknown In case of obvious mistakes in the question, feel free to use your privilege and edit and improve the question. It is actually recommended over commenting: https://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment "When shouldn't I comment? [...] Suggesting corrections that don't fundamentally change the meaning of the post; instead, make or suggest an edit;"

Answer (score 4):

#### Glatteis oder Speiseeis?

Zuerst wäre zu klären, ob Ihre Freundin tatsächlich über die Wettervorhersage spricht (z. B. von Schnee, Hagel, Glatteis). Ohne weiteren Kontext würde ich die Aussage

> - Das Eis ist angesagt.

so verstehen, dass es um irgendein Speiseeis gehe, das sehr begehrt ist.

Das liegt zum einen daran, dass *das Eis* hier mit Artikel verwendet wird, was man eigentlich nur dann tut, wenn von einer konkreten Eiserscheinung (z. B. der Eisüberzug auf meiner Autoscheibe), einer konkreten Eisart (z. B. das Packeis in der Arktis) oder ein konkretes Speiseeis (z. B. das Schokeis in meinem Gefrierfach) die Rede ist.

Zum anderen passt die Wendung *ist angesagt* am ehesten zu Speiseeis, denn in diesem Kontext ist [*angesagt*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/angesagt) ein partizipiales Adjektiv mit der umgangssprachlichen Bedeutung

> sehr begehrt, gefragt; in Mode

#### Kontext Wetterbericht

Wenn es tatsächlich um den Wetterbericht geht, wird *Eis* normalerweise – es gibt natürlich Ausnahmen – ohne Artikel verwendet:

> - Eis ist angesagt. / Es ist Eis angesagt.

Das Verb [*ansagen*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/ansagen) bedeutet in diesem Kontext:

> etw., jmdn., sich ankündigen

Es wird demnach der Aspekt betont, dass etwas angekündigt wird; vor allem im Rundfunk spricht man auch von einer [*Ansage*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Ansage), und die Person, die etwas ansagt, nennt man [*Ansager*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Ansager). Dabei spielt es keine Rolle, ob das, was da angesagt wird, auf Vermutungen beruht; es könnten auch feststehende Tatsachen sein, beispielsweise ein gegenwärtiger Stau auf der Autobahn.

Anders wäre das beim Verb [*vorhersagen*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/vorhersagen), mit dem betont wird, dass etwas aufgrund der Kenntnis von Zusammenhängen oder aufgrund einer Vermutung ausgesagt wird.

Answer (score 3):

*Ansagen* bezieht sich auf sichere Angaben, deswegen meistens der Gegenwart. *Vorhersagen* ist eine Prognose und bezieht sich auf zukünftige oder bislang nicht bekannte Ereignisse auf Basis von Wahrscheinlichkeiten.

Wenn man sich sicher ist, wird "Eis angesagt". Aber wenn man sich nicht sicher ist, wird "Eis vorhergesagt".

Answer (score 3):

Die Bedeutungen überlappen sich; *Wettervorhersage* ist ein fester Begriff, *Wetteransage* ungebräuchlich, trotzdem ist *Schnee ist angesagt* richtig und üblich.

*Ansage* ist eine sprachliche Ankündigung. Das wird auch häufig in Kartenspielen verwendet (z. B. im Skat *Schneider angesagt*), deshalb kann hier auch eine eigene Beteiligung gemeint sein oder die Absicht, etwas herbeiführen zu wollen. (Hier passt Voraussage gar nicht.)

Die feste Redensart z. B.

> Es war ein Sieg des FC Zweifelsheim mit Ansage.

bedeutet, dass sich der Sieg schon abgezeichnet hat, etwa durch gute Leistungen in den vorausgegangenen Spielen

Answer (score 2):

Im Fall der Ankündigung eines bestimmten Wetterphänomens sind beide Verben möglich, jedoch bedeuten sie nicht genau dasselbe. Ein angesagtes Wetter tritt ziemlich sicher ein, bei einem vorhergesagten kann man sich nicht ganz so sicher sein. Der Übergang ist aber fließend.

---

### ansagen

Wenn ein Ereignis, dessen Eintreffen nicht absolut sicher ist, vor seinem Eintreffen ansagt wird, dann geht der/die Ansager davon aus, dass dieses Ereignis mit sehr hoher Wahrscheinlichkeit eintreffen wird. Entweder, weil die äußeren Umstände ein Ausbleiben des Ereignisses sehr unwahrscheinlich machen, oder weil der/die Ansager selbst alles daransetzen wird, das Ereignis herbeizuführen. Das Verb *»ansagen«* wird in diesen Situationen verwendet:

1. Einen Besuch ankündigen

> Hilf mir, wir müssen die Bude aufräumen. Meine Mutter hat sich für heute Abend **angesagt.**

2. Etwas diktieren

> Wenn Sie wollen, dass ich da einen Punkt mache, müssen Sie ihn schon **ansagen.**

3. Auf einer Bühne, im Radio oder Fernsehen: Das nächste Stück ankündigen.

> Der Moderator **sagte** eine Quizshow **an,** aber stattdessen kamen erst mal 8 Minuten Werbung.

4. Etwas über Lautsprecher verkünden.

> Am Bahnhof wurde **angesagt,** dass der Zug heute auf einem anderen Gleis als sonst einfährt.

5. Bei einem Kartenspiel: Trumpf, Stiche, Spielvariante usw. im Voraus bekanntgeben.

> Sepp hat beim Bauernschnapsen einen Gang **angesagt,** dann aber doch nicht alle Stiche gemacht.

6. Eine Wettersituation mit an Sicherheit grenzender Wahrscheinlichkeit vorhersagen.

> Nimm den Schirm mit, für heute Nachmittag ist Regen **angesagt.**

---

Eine ganz andere Bedeutung von *»angesagt«* findet man z.B. in diesem Ausschnitt aus »Helden von heute« von Falco (1982):

> Wir erfinden immer neue Spiele
> Spiele gibt's zu spielen viele
> Brot und Spiele san gefragt
> "No future" extrem **angesagt**

Hier wird »angesagt« als Synonym für »in Mode« verwendet.
<sub>(Das Wort »san« ist nicht Standarddeutsch, es ist dem Wiener Dialekt entlehnt und bedeutet »sind«.)</sub>

---

### vorhersagen

Wenn jemand etwas vorhersagt, dann macht man eine Aussage über die Zukunft, mit der eine nicht zu vernachlässigende Unsicherheit verbunden ist. Der/die Vorhersager selbst mag zwar vielleicht vom Eintreten des Ereignisses überzeugt sein, bei nüchternen Betrachtung muss man aber auch die Möglichkeit des Nichteintretens in Betracht ziehen.

> Paul, die Krake, ist zum Star geworden, weil er bei allen sieben deutschen Spielen sowie beim Finale zwischen Spanien und den Niederlanden den Sieger richtig **vorhergesagt** hatte.

> Es wird behauptet, Nostradamus habe die französische Revolution und den zweiten Weltkrieg **vorhergesagt.**

Auch das, was Meteorologen machen, wird »Vorhersage« genannt, weil mit dem Prognosen der Wissenschaftler Unsicherheiten verbunden sind, die umso größer sind, je weiter entfernt der Zeitpunkt ist, auf den sich die Vorhersage bezieht.

> Für kommende Woche wird in den Becken und Niederungen vermehrtes Aufkommen von Bodennebel **vorhergesagt.**

Comment: Ich bin gerade völlig überrascht, dass _ansagen_ anscheinend so gebräuchlich bei der Wettervorhersage ist. Selbst im Nachhinein würde ich "Der Schnee war vorhergesagt" "Der Schnee wurde angesagt" tausend mal vorziehen.

Comment: @Alex: Vielleicht ist das wieder einer der vielen regionalen Unterschiede, die es in der deutschen Sprache gibt. Ich bin aus dem Osten Österreichs, und zumindest umgangssprachlich wird hierzulande die Floskel »für morgen ist Regen angesagt« erheblich häufiger verwendet als »für morgen wurde Regen vorhergesagt«.

Comment: Ich glaube, dass "angesagt" im ganzen deutschen Sprachraum verwendet und verstanden wird. Einige Beispiele (bitte im Text suchen): [Offenbach Post](https://www.op-online.de/wetter/wetter-deutschland-wird-sommerlich-experte-schlimme-aussichten-zr-13561031.html), [RND](https://www.rnd.de/panorama/trockenheit-in-deutschland-regen-angesagt-waldbrandgefahr-entspannt-sich-trotzdem-wohl-nur-ein-tropfen-auf-dem-heissen-stein-PRDS35QRZRHM5HGM7SRRVCMFAQ.html), [Ruhr24](https://www.ruhr24.de/service/wetter-heute-aktuell-deutschland-nrw-dienstag-woche-experten-warnung-regen-dwd-zr-90075697.html),

Comment: [BZ](https://www.bz-berlin.de/berlin/umland/kein-regen-und-trocknes-laub-erhoehen-waldbrandgefahr-in-brandenburg).